# display formatted text to QTextEdit like in C's printf

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qtextedit

I would like to display a double in qttextedit. For example, if i have

```
double f = 0.0;
```

and I do

```
ui.textEdit->insertPlainText("f = "+ QString::number(f ));
```

I get

> f =0

I would like to show

> f = 0.000

with as many decimal places as I want..

Anyway to do that..

Comment: You could always use `sprintf`... But you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @OlehPrypin: no, you should not because QString(Literal) is your friend there, and even the sprintf function in QString is not recommended for new code. Read the linked documentation in my answer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two Qt options:

1) [QString & QString::sprintf ( const char * cformat, ... )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#sprintf)

```
QString result;
double f = 0.000;
result.sprintf("%.3f", f);
ui.textEdit->insertPlainText(result);
```

2) [QString QString::arg ( double a, int fieldWidth = 0, char format = 'g', int precision = -1, const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' ) ) const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg-20)

```
double f = 0.000;
QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);
standardOutput << QStringLiteral("f = %1").arg(f, 0, 'f', 3) << "\n";
```

Here you can find my test code that is easy to run in order to verify.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    QString result;
    double f = 0.000;
    result.sprintf("%.3f", f);
    QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);
    standardOutput << QStringLiteral("f = %1").arg(f, 0, 'f', 3) << "\n";
    standardOutput << "f = " << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
f = 0.000
f = 0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not test it right now, but I would try `ui.textEdit->insertPlainText(QString("f = %1").arg(f, 5, 'g', -1, QLatin1Char('0')));`

See [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg-20) for more details.

Comment: @Programmer: The code is non-functional (will not even compile) and the link is probably pointing to the wrong method. Also, it is better to use QStringLiteral.

Comment: Thanks, Laszlo.. I did not try the code.. but your answer is much more detailed